# Getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingExceptionr while creating the Java object from json file

Tags: java, json, data-binding

I am trying to create a Java object based on the json file.

```
{  
  "id": "10",  
  "customerId": "199",  
  "startDate": "2017-01-01T01:42:50.622Z"  
}
```

Here is my code snippet

```
String payload = new File(Jsonpath).text;  
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()  
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)  
Bill bill = mapper.readValue(payload, Bill.class)
```

i am getting the following error. Appreciate your help.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.time.OffsetDateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from   
String value ('2017-01-01T01:42:50.622Z')  
 at [Source: {  
  "id": "10",  
  "customerId": "199",  
  "startDate": "2017-01-01T01:42:50.622Z"  
}
```

Comment: Can you please paste the Bill class here?

Comment: You can try using `mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS); `

Comment: problem was resolved by using the following lines                               String payload = new File(Jsonpath).text;                                                       
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()                                              mapper.findAndRegisterModules()